# my channel dose not find in awesome_notifications flutter

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, flutter-getx, awesome-notifications

Hi I want create app with GetX and awesome_notifications, But after i click on button this error is show:
how can fix this? please help.

> W/Android: Awesome Notifications: Channel model
> 'basic_channel' was not found (ChannelManager:88) E/Android: Awesome
> Notifications: Channel 'basic_channel' does not exist
> (NotificationBuilder:58)

this is my controller for the app:

```
class HomeScreenController extends GetxController {
  RxString verb = "".obs;
  RxBool check = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();

    checkOffOn();
    random();


  }

  static void initializeNotificationService() {
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize("assets/images/notification.png", [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        channelName: 'Basic Notifications',
        defaultColor: Colors.teal,
        importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        channelDescription: 'show positive energy every day',
        enableVibration: true,
        enableLights: true,
        //playSound: true,
        //soundSource: ""
      ),
    ]);
  }
 void random() {
    final random = Random();
    verb.value = EnergyList[random.nextInt(EnergyList.length)].sentences;
  }

  void checkOffOn() {
    AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
      if (!isAllowed) {
        check.value = false;
      } else {
        check.value = true;
      }
    });
  }
 void notification() {
    AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
      if (!isAllowed) {
        Get.defaultDialog(
          title: "اعلان ها",
          middleText: 'به برنامه اجازه نمایش اعلان را می دهید؟',
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          textConfirm: 'اجازه می دم',
          cancelTextColor: Colors.black,
          confirmTextColor: Colors.black,
          textCancel: 'بی خیالش',
          buttonColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
          titleStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 2),
          middleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onConfirm: () {
            check.value = true;
            AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
            Get.back();
          },
        );
      } else {
        Get.defaultDialog(
          title: "اعلان ها",
          middleText: 'آیا می خواهید اعلان ها متوقف شود؟',
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          textConfirm: 'آره بشه',
          cancelTextColor: Colors.black,
          confirmTextColor: Colors.black,
          textCancel: 'نه بذار باشه',
          buttonColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
          titleStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 2),
          middleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onConfirm: () {
            check.value = false;
            AwesomeNotifications()
                .cancelNotificationsByChannelKey('basic_channel');
            Get.back();
          },
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> createNotification() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: DateTime.now().microsecond,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: "پیام روز",
        body: "تست",
        backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        color: Colors.black,
        displayOnForeground: true,
        wakeUpScreen: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my home screen button code:

```
ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.createNotification();
                    },
                    child: const Text('تست'),
                  ),
```